# How can i fix a problem with character array?

Tags: c++

[image]

I have set the size of the character array to 2 bytes. But it can hold more than 2 bytes. how is it possible?

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {    
    char a[2];
    std::cout << "enter the name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "the name is " << a << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting some other output
but the output is .....

enter the name
Sami
the name is Sami

Comment: C++ doesn't have any bounds-checking. Going out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so don't do it.

Comment: By including `<string>` and using `string a;` instead of `char a[2];` you wil eliminate a large number of potential pitfalls with your user input. If you want to read a whole name, like `"David C Rankin"`, then you should replace `cin >> a;` with `getline (cin, a);` which will read all characters up until the `'\n'` is encountered. (always validate every user input, e.g. `if (!getline (cin, a)) { /* handle error */ }`)

Answer (score 3):

What happens is that you are effectively writing past the end of the allocated memory.

C++ doesn't check that the input provided fits intothe variable `a` so you are actually writing out of the bounds of the memory allocated to your program, resulting in [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Your program seems to work, but you have actually no guarantees that it will behave as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a fixed size array of char, but use `std::string` instead.

Here is a fixed code example.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main() {    
    std::string a;
    std::cout << "enter the name" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, a);
    std::cout << "the name is " << a << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```